# How to tell vim's intellephense about phpunit classes and methods etc?

Tags: phpunit, neovim, coc.nvim

I'm using [coc-phpls](https://github.com/marlonfan/coc-phpls/) with [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) on neovim to provide intellephense php language server functionality.

It works well, except when I'm working on phpunit code because phpunit includes a load of symbols that the language server can't parse/know about.

Is there a way to tell the language server to parse a .phar file or some other extra dir full of php code when looking for symbols (classes, methods, functions etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to include phpunit as a dev requirement in a composer.json file for your project.

Example:

`composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit '^8.1'`

This will bring in the composer libs and then the IDE will pick them up and give you autocompletions, signatures and all that goodness.

By adding it only to the dev requirements (`--dev`) you're stating that production / releases of this project should not include phpunit.

(I'd still be interested to know if it was possible to add php paths/phar files to the scanned sources some other way.)